# How do I create an array field on a pre-existing document in MongoDB using RESTful Spring Boot?

Tags: arrays, iphone, mongodb, rest, spring-boot

I have been looking all over the internet and there are answers for individual parts of this but I am looking for the best (most efficient) way to go about doing this.

I am creating an app for iPhone and I am currently designing a back end REST service. I know a lot of people will suggest a BaaS but the whole point of the app is because I wanted to create my own backend service. I am stuck at a part where I want to handle Push Notification History. I have already set up a user collection in MongoDB and a UserRepository.java to handle creating new users. However, there is nothing I can find about how to handle adding array entries of objects. (i.e. List)

[Here is a screenshot taken from MongoDB Compass to show a sample user entry:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkBhG.png)

[This is what I want to accomplish:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY0xi.png)

**User.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection="user")
public class User {

    @Id private String id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String token;
    private List<Notification> notificationList;
```

**Notification.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection="notification")
public class Notification extends User {

    @Id private String id;

    private String title;
    private String text;
    private int badge;
    private String sound;
    private String payload;
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    List<User> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
    List<User> findByUserName(@Param("username") String name);

}
```

I am somewhat new to REST and Spring but want to know more about them. I am using RESTful Spring Boot in Spring Tools Suite. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: did you research for `nested array mongodb` ?

Comment: i have the same question, have you found the solution?